# Какие этапы проходит объект в Java, начиная от передачи его через Rest Point и заканчивая тем, как он становится сущностью в методе?

Tags: java, rest

Начал недавно изучать Java и у меня появился вопрос.

Вот у меня есть какое-то сервивисное приложение и у него есть соответствующий контроллер (помеченный аннотацией @Controller) и соответствующие Rest Api методы.
В качестве двигателя используется Spring Boot. Соответсвенно кода минимум. Есть класс Application и класс с контроллером.

Мне вдруг стало интересно (действительно, почему бы это) какие шаги передаваемая сущность проходит под копотом всего этого механизма. И как в итоге моя программа понимает, что вот тот набор параметров, который я задал на входе и является одним из объектов, который я хочу получить по этому мапингу?

К сожалению понятной для меня информации мне найти не удалось. Может у кого завалялась ссылка на хороший источник? Или может кто-то сможет на пальцах рассказать.

Answer (score 1):

тот объект который вы хотите получить, вы явно указываете в параметре метода, а под капотом JSON парсер встроенный в Spring Boot сопоставляет имена параметров которые вы передаете в запросе с именами полей вашего объекта. Сам парсер создает новый объект и заполняет поля через сетерны, если есть не все параметры, они будут null